# Windows Command prompt - Allow user / user group to run a specific command

Tags: windows, command-line, user-profiles, security-policy

I want to allow a specific user group the right to run `format` command.
 I have checked [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/format)  and this is what I have found :

> You must be a member of the Administrators group to format a hard
>   drive.

Is there a way to change that ?

Comment: format permission means hardware disk access, because you need to read/write any sectors. As a result the formatter can read/write any users' files and can't be a normal user

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT my goal is too allow the limited user  to  format **external hard drives and usb sticks **   through the command line .

Answer (score 1):

I think it is. But that would mean that a regualar user also can delete everything on the disk. Do you realy want that?

You could create a scheduled task, mark the option "Run with highest priviledges" & "Allow task to run on demand" and create a shortcut to run the task which formats the disk on the regular users desktop or something.

Comment: Will this work if the user does not have admin privileges?